# Launch Image for iPad pro 12.9 inch

Tags: ipad, launchimage

I have an ipad aplication whose UI is apperaing scale or "Display Zoom" on ipad pro 12.9 inch.
This is because of not using correct Launch image.

I have found that the dimension of launch image for ipad pro - 12.9 inch is = 2048 x 2732

When I am trying to add correct images in media.xcasset, there is no placeholder for ipad pro.

How can I add the correct lauch image for ipad pro so that the UI will not be zoomed.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score -1):

**`LaunchImage` support below iOS 8, So iOS 8+ versions you have to use `LaunchScreen`.**

If your app universal support (Both iPhone / iPad) then create two separate `LauchScreen.storyboard`

- Create two `storyboard`

  LaunchScreeniPhone.storyboard
  LaunchScreeniPad.storyboard
- Set imageView in storyboard and set large image in imageView.
- Then add key and value in info.plist file for both LauchScreen.storyboard.

  `<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
      <string>LaunchScreeniPhone</string>`

  `<key>UILaunchStoryboardName~ipad</key>
     <string>LaunchScreeniPad</string>`
- Finally set LaunchScreen in **General -> App Icons and Lauch images -> LauchScreen -> LauchScreeniPhone.**